# Razorpay Subscriptions API item price can not be set

Tags: javascript, razorpay

I am using RazorPay API to create Subscription plans. Now, I am facing this error :

When I add item amount in number it sends me error : Amount should be atleast 0.10 USD , https://prnt.sc/Gh9wWm363szh
When I add item amount in decimal it sends me error : Amount should be integer : https://prnt.sc/x6toKYCvF3vj

code :

```js
try{
  const data = await razorpay.items.create(body);
  res.status(200).send(data);
}catch(err){
  console.log(err);
  res.status(400).send({
    message:err?.error?.description
  });
}
```

any help.
screenshots from API calls .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most payment apis use cents instead of dollers.

so if you want `5` doller then put `500` as the value

`value = dollar_value * 100`

your api min is `10` which is `$0.10`

review the [documentation](https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/subscriptions/)